# How can we populate values in one select box when changing values of another select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

When I select a value from select box named `State` I want to populate values in corresponding select box named `Region`. How can I solve this.

Below I've given my design and code.[image]

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12{{ $errors->has('state') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <div class="field-label">State <span class="required">*</span></div>
         {!! Form::select('state', $states, "",[]) !!}

             @if ($errors->has('state'))
                  <span class="help-block">
                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('state') }}</strong>
                  </span>
             @endif
    </div>
<!-- Region Selection  -->
<div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12{{ $errors->has('region') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <div class="field-label">Region <span class="required">*</span></div>
         {!! Form::select('region', $regions, "",[]) !!}

             @if ($errors->has('region'))
                 <span class="help-block">
                 <strong>{{ $errors->first('region') }}</strong>
                 </span>
             @endif
     </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have all the state and regions on the page load, then go for the below code. No need for ajax call

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#state").change(function(){
    $("#region .reg").hide();
    $("#region .state_"+$(this).val()).show();
    $("#region").val("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="state">
  <option value="1">Kerala</option>
  <option value="2">Tamil Nadu</option>
  <option value="3">Karnataka</option>
</select>

<select id="region">
  <option value="">Select Region</option>
  <option value="1" class="reg state_1">Trivandrum</option>
  <option value="2" class="reg state_1">Kollam</option>
  <option value="3" class="reg state_2">Chennai</option>
  <option value="3" class="reg state_2">Coibathur</option>
  <option value="3" class="reg state_3">Banglure</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This won't work on Safari. You can't use `display:none` on `<option>` elements in Safari. This also won't work on iOS devices, either.

Comment: @Aneesh RS....Thanks for code...I've converted it to laravel and its working. If it is a good question please Upvote

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax for this purpose.

```
<select name="state" id="state" onchange="bringRegion(this.value)">
...
...
...
</select>

<select id="region" name="region">

</select>


//Ajax part
<script>
   function bringRegion(selected)
   {
      $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "your_route",
          data: "state="+selected,
          success: function(result)
          {
             $("#region").html(result);
          }
       });
   }
</script>
```

Just return `options` from your controller.

Comment: to where i want to return the options

Comment: Create a function in your controller for this purpose and return HTML options via Ajax response.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple options at your disposal.

If you're loading up Regions at page lad, hopefully you have some relationship between the region and the state in the backend, let's say that `region belongsTo state` and `state` has a property `name` for our example

In that case, you can loop over all regions and use `data attributes` inside of a `hidden div`. Then when you select the state, you can build each of the options from this `hidden div` using the corresponding `data attributes`. Something like this:

```
<div class="hidden-regions" style="display:none;">
   @foreach($regions as $region)
       <div data-state="{{$region->state->name}}" data-region="{{$region->name}}"></div>
   @endforeach
</div>
```

Then you can use jQuery to populate the `select` dropdown when you choose an option from the `state` dropdown.

```
$('select[name="state"]').on('change', function(){
    let $state = $(this);
    let $regionSelect = $('select[name="region"]');

    $regionSelect.empty(); // remove all options from the region

    // loop our hidden divs to find matching regions by state selected val
    $('.hidden-regions > div').each(function(){
        let $region = $(this);

        // if our data-state attribute matches the selected state value
        if ($region.data('state') === $state.val()) {
           $state.append('<option value="'+ $region.data('region') +'">'+ $region.data('region') +'</option>');
        }
    });

});
```

Or, you can use ajax for this, as I was writing it out, someone posted it. The advantage here is that you don't have to make an endpoint just for getting regions. The disadvantage here is that jQuery sucks and this is messy.